# Run Time Error "713"

Tags: windows, vb6, report

I have a program built in vb6. The code has been working fine in all environments. However when i am working with it in the windows 8 environment i get this runtime error. It happens when we run the vbreports contained inside a form. Anything with the .dsr extension gives this run time error 713. I have checked dlls and they seem to be installed on the OS. It's only windows 8 x64 that has this problem. Haven't tried x86.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to fix it by re-registering dlls.

```
<windows system>\Msdbrptr.dll
<program files>\Common Files\Designers\Msderun.dll
<windows system>\Msstdfmt.dll
```

> Eg:
>
> Open command prompt and choose Run as Administrator

```
%systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32 "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Msdbrptr.dll"
%systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\designer\Msderun.dll"
%systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32 "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Msstdfmt.dll"
```

Comment: Properly installing VB6 would register those libraries.  This suggests you have a nightmare of registration errors, probably virtualized, waiting to burn you time and time again.  The need to manually register these is a symptom of a problem, not a cure.